# If a sin is not intentional but due to psychological or physical reasoning, will Jesus Christ still count that act as a sin?

Tags: catholicism, sin, forgiveness

Sin is really vicious and annoying to God.

But what if a sin that is caused by a person's physical or mental ailments does God look upon that person with empathy, sympathy, and compassion?

For example, a person might have anger management problems due to his mental illnesses even though he is seeing a psychiatrist, therapist and taking med regularly. He is not into himself. What if he is deeply repentant after the act. But he continues to show anger. Because his physical and mental world does not cooperate with the spiritual realm. What if he is trying every day with all his body, mind and soul to get over it and taking baby steps. But he does not know when this burning problem will be resolved. Will Christ still look at him with Mercy? Or other acts related to mental and physical illnesses that are offending to God but the intention is not fully present. They are helpless. They wish that Christ would cure them immediately so that they would not commit those acts against God.

St. Paul was about to obliterate Christians and on the way, Christ showed his face in the cloud. And he never took up the sword again. He was cured of his sinful ways.

In the Bible, we also have a mentally ill teenage boy at the foot of the hill who was behaving erratically. Jesus Christ showed sympathy toward that boy.

If sin is not intentional but due to psychological or physical reasoning, does Jesus Christ still count that act as a sin? What does the Catechism of the Catholic Church say about it?

Comment: Did you take a look at the catechism before you asked the question?  [There's an English version here](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/_INDEX.HTM).  {Not going to say their prose style is the most concise - it isn't, it is quite laborious - so I don't doubt that you'll have a few questions/clarifications once you review that}   [The sacrament of penance and reconciliation probably covers what you are looking for](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P46.HTM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If a sin is not intentional but due to psychological or physical reasoning, will Jesus Christ still count that act as a sin?**

Circumstances can definitely diminish the culpability of a sin in an individual and in some cases it may be negated completely of any culpability.

Here is what the **Catechism of the Catholic Church** has to say on this subject:

> [1860](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p3s1c1a8.htm) *Unintentional ignorance* can diminish or even remove the imputability of a grave offense. But no one is deemed to be ignorant of the principles of the moral law, which are written in the conscience of every man. The promptings of feelings and passions can also diminish the voluntary and free character of the offense, as can external pressures or pathological disorders. Sin committed through malice, by deliberate choice of evil, is the gravest.

Answer (score 0):

Sin is what we have inherited from Adam. So we all have sinned and fall short of the glory ("value") [if you will permit me to say]) of God. 1John 3:8 (King James Bible Version) He that committeth sin is of the devil; for the devil sinneth from the beginning. **For this purpose the Son of God was maninifested, that He might destroy the works of the devil.**
So I have sinned, this is why I have come to the conclusion that the purpose God meant for the coming of His Son Jesus is to save me from the eternal effects of my sin: "separation from God (in Heaven) forever". It is not that I am sinless, but that by my personal relationship with God, (in faith of Christ), but that I sin less;
  Galatians 2: 16-20 KJV Knowing that a man is not justified by the works of the law (Ten Commandments), but by the faith of Jesus Christ, even we have believed in Jesus Christ, that we might be justified by the faith of Christ, and not by the works of the law; for by the works of the law shall no flesh be justified. But if, while we seek to be justified by Christ, we ourselves also are found sinners, is therefore Christ the minister of sin? God forbid. For if I build again the things which I destroyed, I make myself a transgressor. For I through the law am dead to the law, that I might live unto God.
 I am crucified with Christ: nevertheless I live; yet not I, but Christ liveth in me: and the life which I now live in the flesh I live by faith of the Son of God, who loved me, and gave Himself for me.
1John 1:5-10
This then is the message which we heard of Him, and declare unto you, that God is light, and in Him there is no darkness at all. If we say that we have fellowship with Him, and walk in darkness we lie, an do not the truth: But if we walk in the Light , as He is in the Light, we have fellowship with one another, and the blood of Jesus Christ His Son cleanseth us from all sin. If we say that we have no sin, we deceive ourselves, and the truth is not in us. If we confess our sins (to each other and to God), He is faithful and just to forgive us our sins, and cleanse us from all unrighteousness. If we say that we have not sinned, we make Him a liar, and His word is not in us.
 I will and must continue to make God's will my own and my own will I will surrender to God, so that I might not sin against Him. And if I do sin I will confess my sin to a trusted brethren (in Christ) and God, so that I will be cleansed from all unrighteousness and continue in an unbroken relationship with God (in Christ).

Comment: Welcome John. The question asks this from the catholic perspective (check the tag on the question) so if you could please support your answer from that perspective it would be useful.  [Ask] and [Answer] guidance is available.  The [tour] provides a review on how SE sites are not discussion forums.